# Functions loops and array

Tags: arrays, function, loops

```
    def write_schedule(week_timetable, open_time_table):
        print "Please enter Weeks sechdule: "
        week = [mon,tues,wed,thur,fri,sat,sun]
        for i in week:
             print "Please enter day 1: "
            # here i would like to input a time into each variable within       the week array i have created
           # later on in my script i would like to insert each time into my global array 
          # week_timetable = ["Mon: %s ", "Tues: %s ", "Wed: %s ", "Thurs: %s ", "Fri: %s", "Sat: %s", "Sun %s"]
```

I'm trying to use a loop to input each time into an array list. I want to put raw input from the user and then save it into each array. After the function has done the loop I wish to save each variable into my global array. I'm kinda stuck with this one, if I am not making sense then refer to my comments in my above code.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming all the dates are objects that take data. If so I call `for day in week` to make it clearer and then add the user input to the day object as modeled.

if the week is just an array of arrays then you can use `day.append(input)` within the same loop. when you are done the loop the week array will contain all the modified objects/arrays for you to do as you please.